# Как правильно сортировать массив по годам

Tags: php

Как правильно сортировать массив по годам?

```
    $nazv = $rest."_".$bezyear."<br/>"; //2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_<br/>2017_acura_cdx_<br/>2013_acura_ilx_endurance_racer_<br/>2017_acura_mdx_<br/>2016_acura_nsx_<br/>2017_acura_nsx_


rsort($nazv);
echo $nazv; // Не сортирует 2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_<br/>2017_acura_cdx_<br/>2013_acura_ilx_endurance_racer_<br/>2017_acura_mdx_<br/>2016_acura_nsx_<br/>2017_acura_nsx_
```

Как правильно отсортировать массив с помощью переменной?

Полный код:

```
$dir = "./";
$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);


for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
  if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_") {
    $shortname = substr($name[$i], 0, -4);
    $bezyear = substr($shortname, 0, -4);   
    $rest = substr($shortname, -4);
    $nazv = $rest."_".$bezyear."<br/>";


rsort($nazv);
echo $nazv;


    $namenew = str_replace('_', ' ', $nazv);
    $namenew = ucwords($namenew); 
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><img src='./img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' width='172px'></a><br/></td>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><center>".$namenew."</center></a><br/></td>
    </tr>";




  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `$sortyear = $nazv;`, ибо у вас получается массив в массиве

Comment: Объединяю дату и название `$nazv = $rest."_".$bezyear."<br/>";` получаю массив `2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_<br/>2017_acura_cdx_<br/>2013_acura_ilx_endurance_racer_<br/>2017_acura_mdx_<br/>2016_acura_nsx_<br/>2017_acura_nsx_<br/>` Пытаюсь сортировать `rsort($nazv);
echo $nazv;` - не сортирует: `2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_<br/>2017_acura_cdx_<br/>2013_acura_ilx_endurance_racer_<br/>2017_acura_mdx_<br/>2016_acura_nsx_<br/>2017_acura_nsx_<br/>2016_acura_nsx__`

Comment: `2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_<br/>2017_acura_cdx_<br/>2013‌​_acura_ilx_endurance‌​_racer_<br/>2017_acu‌​ra_mdx_<br/>2016_acu‌​ra_nsx_<br/>2017_acu‌​ra_nsx_<br/>` - это не массив, а строка

Comment: Попробуйте розделить с помощю `explode()` указав в качестве розделителя `<br/>`

Answer (score 2):

Неправильная сортировка - следствие того, что вы положили массив в массив.
 Получается, что вы пытаетесь отсортировать массив, в котором лежит один элемент(который массив, но это уже не важно). Зачем вам вообще использоваться эту переменную `$sortyear`? Делайте просто сортировку по массиву `$nazv` да и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

$files = array();
foreach ($name as $file) {
    if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_")
    {
        $shortname = substr($name[$i], 0, -4);
        $without_year = substr($shortname, 0, -4);   
        $year = substr($shortname, -4);
        $files[$year] = $without_year;
    }
}

asort($files);

foreach ($files as $nazv) {
    $namenew = str_replace('_', ' ', $nazv);
    $namenew = ucwords($namenew); 
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><img src='./img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' width='172px'></a><br/></td>
        <td><a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'><center>".$namenew."</center></a><br/></td>
    </tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `rsort();
echo implode((string)$filler,$nazv);
echo $nazv;` - Ничего не поменялось. $nazv - объединение двух переменных год (в начало для использования в сортировке) и название 2016_ac_schnitzer_acl2_concept_

Comment: @Sergey_777 выложите где нибудь более подробный код, или хотя бы полноценный участок кода. А то так как котята, в слепую тыкаться буду.

Comment: Полный код добавил...

Comment: @Sergey_777 попробуй этот код ^

Comment: Выводит пустое img со ссылкой на эту же страницу...

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший вариант в моем случае использовать Сортировку столбцов в таблице без перезагрузки, тогда все становиться на места http://htmlweb.ru/java/example/sort_table2.php